# How to replace the last one or two characters of a file with unix tools

Tags: unix, file

I have a hanging comma at the end of a file that I would like to replace with a close square bracket.  There may or may not be a newline character at the end of the file as well.  How can I replace the one or two characters with the square bracket using common unix tools?

Comment: File contents... sorry about that Jonathan.  Didn't see your question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete all trailing empty lines and then replace the last comma in the file with a ']'

```
cat origfile | sed -e :a -e '/^\n*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' | sed -e '$s/,$/]/'  > outputfile
```

Comment: Brian, thanks for this one.  I didn't realize until trying things out that the above suggestions replace *all* commas with closing square brackets rather.  Your second sed statement is just what I was looking for.

Comment: Umm, huh?  Matt's answer is the only one that might be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, text files should end with a newline.

One way to edit a file for replace trailing comma with close bracket on last line is:

```
ed - $file <<'!'
$s/,$/]/
w
q
!
```

This goes to the last line, replaces the trailing comma with close bracket, and writes and exits.  Alternatively, using sed:

```
sed '$s/,$/]/' $file > new.$file &&
mv new.$file $file
```

If you have GNU sed, there is an 'overwrite' option ('-i', IIRC).

If you need to deal with file names rather than file contents, then:

```
newname=$(echo "$oldname" | sed 's/,$/]/')
```

And no doubt there are other mechanisms too.  You could also use Perl or Python; they tend towards overkill for the example requested.

Comment: I think I'm probably not understanding the `sed` properly. Wouldn't a trailing newline cause the $ to jump to the empty line, upon which it would not find a comma and promptly exit?

Comment: No, `$` means "last line".  The last line can end with `\n` (which is usually the case in UNIX); it will still be the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Sed can easily do a replace on the last line only:

```
sed '$ s/,/]/g' inputFile
```

The $ address selector indicates the last line.

If the file ended with a newline, this would not change that, however.  Is that really a desired behavior, or do you just want to replace the last , with ]?

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  And yes, you're right, I don't really care about whether or not there is a newline, I just want the comma replaced.  Thanks!

Comment: The command replaces all commas of the last line. You should use `'$ s/,$/]/'` if you want only the last comma replaced.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i -pe'BEGIN{undef$/}s/,\n?\Z/]/'
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a faster method compared to use sed for big files, assuming last line is not a newline

```
head -n -1 file > temp;
s=$(tail -1 file)
echo ${s/%,/]} >> temp
echo mv temp file
```